Polar rotations of sphere using tikz-3dplot
I want to spin a circle about the z axis after a rotation about the y axis, but am not getting the desired result.
I can do polar rotations with the lines of latitude:

But for longitudinal lines, I get a problem where they rotate in their given reference frame, so it looks more like a Fabergé egg:

I tried replacing \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\Vthe+\Vazi}{90+\Vpol}{0} with \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90+\Vpol}{\Vthe+\Vazi} to do the y-axis rotation first, then the z-axis one, but I must be misunderstanding the syntax.
The goal is to animate a sphere rotating in arbitrary directions.
Here's my somewhat MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
%%% PACKAGES %%%
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}
%%% DEFINITIONS %%%
\newcommand{\Vazi}{120}
\newcommand{\Vpol}{30}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{50}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
%%% OUTTER ELLIPSE %%%
\draw[very thin,tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0,0) circle(1);
\draw[-latex] (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[pos=1]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0) node[pos=1]{$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,-3) -- (0,0,3) node[pos=1]{$z$};
%%% FOREACH LOOP %%%
\foreach \Vthe in {0, 10, ..., 350}{
%%% LONGITUTE %%%
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\Vthe+\Vazi}{90+\Vpol}{0}
% \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\Vazi}{90}{\Vthe} doesn't work for some reason
\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,very thin,spath/save=pathname] (0,0,0) circle(1);
\path[draw,black,very thin,spath/use={pathname, transform={shift={({0},{0},{0})}}}];
%%% LATITUTE %%%
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\Vazi}{\Vpol}{0}
\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,very thin,spath/save=pathname] (0,0,0) circle [radius={cos(\Vthe)}];
\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,draw,blue,very thin,spath/use={pathname, transform={shift={({0},{0},{sin(\Vthe)})}}}];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

And it gives this:


doing \Vpol*cos(\Vthe) fixes it a bit, but stops working for larger angles

I found that using parametric plots works better for this task, as they allow for further editing. I still used tikz-3dplot to rotate it afterwards, but I think that making the parametric equations more elaborate may be the better way - I'd be interested to see a post accomplishing this. In the meantime, here's my fix:
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
%%% PACKAGES %%%
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}
%%% DEFINITIONS %%%
\newcommand{\Vazi}{45}
\newcommand{\Vpol}{45}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
%%% OUTTER ELLIPSE %%%
\draw[very thin,tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0,0) circle(1);
\draw[-latex] (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[pos=1]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0) node[pos=1]{$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,-3) -- (0,0,3) node[pos=1]{$z$};


\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\Vazi}{\Vpol}{0}
\foreach \Vthe in {0, 10, ..., 170}{
%%% LONGITUTE %%%
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords,very thin,domain=0:360,smooth,variable=\t] plot ({cos(\t)*sin(\Vthe)},{sin(\t)*sin(\Vthe)},{cos(\Vthe)});
%%% LATITUDE %%%
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords,very thin,domain=0:360,smooth,variable=\t] plot ({cos(\t)*cos(\Vthe)},{cos(\t)*sin(\Vthe)},{sin(\t)});
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


